# PHP MyAdmin SQL isn't Allowing me to Alter MySQL Table and Giving the Error #1064

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to alter an existing table using the PHP MyAdmin run SQL. I have typed in the code `ALTER TABLE file
ADD orderid int(11)NOT NULL
ADD title varchar(200) NOT NULL
ADD description VARCHAR(700) NOT NULL
ADD make VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
ADD model VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
ADD year VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
ADD price VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL`

and I am getting the error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ADD title varchar(200) NOT NULL ADD description VARCHAR(700) NOT NULL ADD make' at line 3`.

Thank you, for any help. I appreciate all help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing commas after each column:

```
ALTER TABLE file 
ADD orderid int(11)NOT NULL, -- <-- HERE
ADD title varchar(200) NOT NULL , -- <-- HERE
```

etc